# Google chart with local excel sheet

Tags: excel, google-visualization

Is it possible to use local excel sheet with [google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart)? If so, how can the google chart read the local excel sheet.

There are options for reading google spreadsheet but i am currently struggling with reading local excel sheet.